# Formatear fecha en foreach Laravel 8 y Livewire

Tags: laravel

Hola soy nuevo con *laravel* y *livewire* y me esta costando demasiado entender como formatear una fecha adicional a esto encuentro muy poca información ¿me pueden dar una mano con mi código?

Donde yo muestro mis fechas lo tengo así:

```
@foreach ($changelogs as $value)
<h1 class="text-md font-extrabold ">{{$value->created_at}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Donde recupero mis datos de la bd para mostrarlos en la vista lo tengo así.

```
 public function render()

 {
     $changelogs = Changelog::all();
     return view('livewire.changelog-component', compact('changelogs'));

 }

De antemano gracias espero me puedan ayudar.
```

Comment: Y que formato es el que quieres darle?

Comment: 2020-12-03 12:18:00 Me devuelve esta fecha quiero pasarla a Dic 03, 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value->created_at)) }}
```

Convertirá la fecha al formato `d-m-Y` que le haya dado.

**Nota:** Esta solución es una solución general que funciona para php y cualquiera de sus marcos. Para un método específico de Laravel, pruebe la solución proporcionada por [Hamelraj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page/40038594#40038594).

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfectamente, el código me quedo así al final `{{date('M d, Y', strtotime($changelog->created_at))}}`